# how to get unread email from gmail using go?

Tags: go, gmail, gmail-api

In Python ,I can use

```
unread_msgs = GMAIL.users().messages().list(userId='me', labelIds=['INBOX', 'UNREAD']).execute()
```

get unread email,
the go api

```
func (r *UsersMessagesService) List(userId string) *UsersMessagesListCall
```

don't have label parameter, how to do it ?
thk

Answer (score 0):

I did not try it in Go, but it should be something like:

```
Users.Messages.List(userId).Q("label:INBOX,label:UNREAD").Do()
```